# AngularJS $http.get products

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

i created my new store in angularjs. In there i have a function called store, where it gets all my products. In the start i just wrote all the products in there, but now i want to get them from a mysql database. I think that the problem is something in the $http.get, but dont know what.

Before my function looked like this:

```
function store() {
    this.products = [
        { num: 1, code: 'TEST', category: 'Diverse', name: 'TEST', src: "test.png", description: 'info her', price: 2, cal: 10 }
    ];
}
```

Which worked. I created the code below, with the $http.get, and that code dont show anything in my store:

```
function store() {

    $http.get('products.php')
        .success(function(data) {
            this.products = data;
        });

}
```

My products.php file echo this and it does encode to json:

```
[{"num":"1","code":"TET","category":"Diverse","name":"Test","src":"test.png","description":"Test","price":"5","cal":"10"}]
```

products.php file:

```
require('scripts/connect.php');

$statement = $conn->prepare("select * from products");
$statement->execute();

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

  foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    $prod[$key] = $value;
  }

  $main_arr[] = $prod;
}

$json = json_encode($main_arr); 
echo $json;
```

Extra code for help:

controller.js

```
function storeController($scope, $routeParams, DataService) {
    // get store and cart from service
    $scope.store = DataService.store;
    $scope.cart = DataService.cart;
}
```

app.js

```
storeApp.factory("DataService", function () {

    // create store
    var myStore = new store();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that $http is injected into the controller or service

Comment: Not really, how do i do that?

Comment: where did you define your store function !

Comment: My store function is in "store.js"

Comment: i mean did you define it inside a controller or a service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know how your code works, but you said that this code is working fine:

```
function store() {
    this.products = [
        { num: 1, code: 'TEST', category: 'Diverse', name: 'TEST', src: "test.png", description: 'info her', price: 2, cal: 10 }
    ];
}
```

And I'm assuming you have an access to the `$http` somehow.

To convert the above code to use the `$http`, it should be like this instead:

```
function store() {
    var self = this;

    $http.get('products.php')
        .success(function(data) {
            self.products = data;
        });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, that didnt change the error, still Error: store is not a constructor. I've searched the other files and it doesnt say anything about $http. So i dont think theres any access to it..

Comment: Then I couldn't help further unless seeing more code. Could you include more code in the question?

Comment: Just edited, there is more code in the files, but thats for the cart and other stuff. Right now i just deleted the inject $http code, that Aaron sent, where should i put it? Before i putted it in the same file as my store function, dont know if that change anything?

Comment: The version of angularjs is 1.1.5, do you think its because of that?

Comment: No, this is not related to angularjs version, but how your code is organized. If you still haven't solved the problem, I will have an another look at your code when I have time.

Comment: My code is organized like this: app.js, cart.js controller.js and store.js. But if the http.get dont work, there may be another way, with push or something.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you've properly [injected](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) module into your controller (or service, however you're going about it).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('storeController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.store = {products: getData()};

    function getData() {
        $http.get('products.php')
          .success(function(data) {
              return data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I just inserted that code inside where the function were. With that code it gives me this error: "Error: store is not a constructor

Comment: Well you're mixing logic in with an object constructor, I'll modify my above code to reflect a different way of going about it.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using `this` rather than `AngularJS`'s `$scope` to hold your data?

Comment: Don't know why, bought the shop from another guy.

Comment: $scope.store = {products: getData()}; doesnt seem to work either :/